# How to append (%) percentage sign without multiplying in XLSX JS

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

In XLSX, unable to append a cell value with % symbol. While trying, it's multiplying the cell value by 100.

Input: ["Ball", 1000, 201.72].

Expected output in XLSX: ["Ball", 1000, 201.72%]

Current output: ["Ball", 1000, 20172.00%]

```
function test(){
  var itemArr = [
    ["Ball", 1000, 201.72],
    ["Bell", 800, 0.7],
    ["Bun", 1500, 1.7612]
  ];
  var arrayOfArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < itemArr.length; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < itemArr[i].length; j++) {
      var obj = {};
      obj.v = itemArr[i][j];
      if (j > 0) obj.t = "n";
      else obj.t = "s";
      if (j == 2) obj.z = "#,##0.00%";
      else if (j == 1) obj.z = "#,##0.00";
      row.push(obj);
    }
    arrayOfArray.push(row);
  }
  var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(arrayOfArray);
  var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Sheet1");
  return XLSX.writeFile(wb, "test.xlsx");
}
```

Here's the sample codepen: https://codepen.io/satishvarada/pen/yLMajKe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a number formatter similar to Excel's so whenever you use the percentage sign it automatically multiplies by 100.

Via SheetJS documentation

> The rules are slightly different from how Excel displays custom number formats. In particular, literal characters must be wrapped in double quotes or preceded by a backslash. For more info, see the Excel documentation article Create or delete a custom number format or ECMA-376 18.8.31 (Number Formats)

You can add a percentage literal by adding quotes around it

```
if (j == 2) obj.z = '#,#0.00"%"';
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/JonathanSouthern/pen/PopbbZr

Answer (score -1):

Remove the "%" from the format and append it to the value afterwards. Here is the relevant change:

```
if (j == 2) {
   obj.z = "#,##0.00";
   obj.v += '%';
}
```

Updated code:

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var itemArr = [
    ["Ball", 1000, 201.72],
    ["Bell", 800, 0.7],
    ["Bun", 1500, 1.7612]
  ];
  var arrayOfArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < itemArr.length; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < itemArr[i].length; j++) {
      var obj = {};
      obj.v = itemArr[i][j];
      if (j > 0) obj.t = "n";
      else obj.t = "s";
      if (j == 2) {
        obj.z = "#,##0.00"; // No percent sign here
        obj.v += '%'; // Append it afterwards
      }
      else if (j == 1) obj.z = "#,##0.00";
      row.push(obj);
    }
    arrayOfArray.push(row);
  }
  var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(arrayOfArray);
  var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Sheet1");
  return XLSX.writeFile(wb, "test.xlsx");
});
```

https://codepen.io/km0ser/pen/dyvOOPj